# Compiling and running Yaws appmods

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, yaws, erlangweb

Appmods are a way to let the application programmer take control over the URL path. They are implemented as Erlang modules. For example myappmod.erl

```
-module(myappmod).
-include("../../yaws_api.hrl").
-compile(export_all).

out(Arg) ->
    Method = (Arg#arg.req)#http_request.method,
    handle(Method, Arg).

handle(Method,Arg) ->
    %%  Do something 
    ok.
```

How should I carry out the compiling to make this appmod easily manageable?

In which directory of the yaws directory tree should I save the myappmod.erl and where does the myappmod.beam go after compiling?

How do generate the URL path to refer to this appmod?

All the help is welcomed!

Answer (score 4):

Compiling your appmod is a matter of calling the [`erlc` compiler](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlc.html). You then install the resulting beam file into a load directory known to Yaws, which are specified in the `yaws.conf` file using the `ebin_dir` directive:

```
ebin_dir = /path/to/some/ebin
ebin_dir = /path/to/another/ebin
```

You can specify your own paths here. Multiple `ebin_dir` settings are cumulative — all such paths are added to the Yaws load path.

For actively developing your appmod, with automatic reloading of your changes, you can use something like [the `sync` project](https://github.com/rustyio/sync).

The URL for your appmod is also specified in `yaws.conf`, in a `server` block, using the `appmods` directive. You can find examples in the [Yaws documentation](http://yaws.hyber.org/appmods.yaws). For example, if you want your appmod to control the whole URL space for a server, you specify `/` as its URL path:

```
<server foo>
    port = 8001
    listen = 0.0.0.0
    docroot = /filesystem/path/to/www
    appmods = </, myappmod>
</server>
```

Note also the optional `exclude_paths` directive you can specify in an `appmods` setting, typically used for excluding paths storing statically loaded resources. For example, the following setting means that `myappmod` handles the entire URL space `/` except for any URL path starting with `/icons`:

```
appmods = </, myappmod exclude_paths icons>
```

Comment: @Vinoski the solution is very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: It is very helpful. Thanks